# how opshub support sync between vstf and vso?

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I know that Opshub migration tool is used for migrating from the VSTF to VSO, but It is not supporting synchronization between VSTF and VSO.
Is there any way to use the OpsHub Integration Manager to do synchronization between VSTF and VSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. OpsHub Integration Manager supports bi-directional synchronization between a wide variety of systems including Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio Online. It can be used for bi-directional sync between TFS and VSO. For more information please reach out to OpsHub at http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/company/contactus